# zend framework paginator (Zend_Paginator) results too slow

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I have a query that running way too slow. the page takes a few minutes to load.
I'm doing a table join on tables with over 100,000 records. In my query, is it grabbing all the records or is it getting only the amount I need for the page? Do I need to put a limit in the query? If I do, won't that give the paginator the wrong record count?

```
$paymentsTable = new Donations_Model_Payments();
$select = $paymentsTable->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('p' => 'tbl_payments'), array('clientid', 'contactid', 'amount'))
    ->where('p.clientid = ?', $_SESSION['clientinfo']['id'])
    ->where('p.dt_added BETWEEN  \''.$this->datesArr['dateStartUnix'].'\' AND \''.$this->datesArr['dateEndUnix'].'\'')
        ->join(array('c' => 'contacts'), 'c.id = p.contactid', array('fname', 'mname', 'lname'))
        ->group('p.id')
        ->order($sortby.' '.$dir)
        ;
        $payments=$paymentsTable->fetchAll($select);

// paginator
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($payments);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page'), 1);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage('100'); // items pre page
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;

$payments=$payments->toArray();
$this->view->payments=$payments;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see revised code below. You need to pass the `$select` to `Zend_Paginator` via the correct adapter. Otherwise you won't see the performance benefits.

```
$paymentsTable = new Donations_Model_Payments();
$select = $paymentsTable->select(Zend_Db_Table::SELECT_WITH_FROM_PART);
$select->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->joinLeft('contacts', 'tbl_payments.contactid = contacts.id')
    ->where('tbl_payments.clientid = 39')
    ->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('tbl_payments.dt_added BETWEEN "1262500129" AND "1265579129"'))
    ->group('tbl_payments.id')
    ->order('tbl_payments.dt_added DESC');

// paginator
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select));
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_getParam('page', 1));
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage('100'); // items pre page
$this->view->paginator = $paginator;
```

Please see revised code above!

Comment: Thank you Simon, but I tried it and it still just hangs there.
If I run the same query through PhpMyAdmin it runs in a second with 16,000 results. Here is the query:

SELECT  tbl_payments.clientid, tbl_payments.contactid, tbl_payments.amount ,
contacts .fname, contacts.mname, contacts.lname
 FROM tbl_payments
LEFT JOIN `contacts` ON contacts.id = tbl_payments.contactid

WHERE tbl_payments.clientid=39 AND (tbl_payments.dt_added BETWEEN '1262500129' AND '1265579129')
GROUP BY tbl_payments.id
ORDER BY tbl_payments.dt_added DESC

Comment: Is there a way to use a plain sql query to use for the paginator? Maybe it will work with that.

Comment: My Bad. I should have looked at your entire code. It works!! Thank you very much Simon. Looks like I need the Zend_Db_Expr for some queries.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you are :

- first, selecting and fetching all records that match your condition

  - see the `select` ... `from`... and all that
  - and the call to `fetchAll` on the line just after
- and, only the, you are using the paginator,

  - on the results returned by the `fetchAll` call.

With that, I'd say that, yes, all your 100,000 records are fetched from the DB, manipulated by PHP, passed to `Zend_Paginator` which has to work with them... only to discard almost all of them.

Using [`Zend_Paginator`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html), you should be able to pass it an instance of `Zend_Db_Select`, and let it execute the query, specifying the required `limit`.

Maybe the example about [DbSelect and DbTableSelect adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.usage.html) might help you understand how this can be achieved *(sorry, I don't have any working example)*.

Comment: But if I use a limit on the query, won't the pagination results be incorrect? It might show the wrong amount of pages because I'm telling it that there are fewer results. Or do I need to do 2 queries, one for the paginator and one for the results? Not sure.

Comment: You should not *(from what I understand)* do a query yourself : you should let `Zend_Paginator` do the query, specifying the right `limit` itself -- and it will know the right amount of pages (it'll do a `count` query, I suppose)

Answer (score 1):

I personally count the results via COUNT(*) and pass that to zend_paginator. I never understood why you'd deep link zend_paginator right into the database results. I can see the pluses and minuses, but really, its to far imho.

Bearing in mind that you only want 100 results, you're fetching 100'000+ and then zend_paginator is throwing them away. Realistically you want to just give it a count.

```
    $items      = Eurocreme_Model::load_by_type(array('type' => 'list', 'from' => $from, 'to' => MODEL_PER_PAGE, 'order' => 'd.id ASC'));
    $count      = Eurocreme_Model::load_by_type(array('type' => 'list', 'from' => 0, 'to' => COUNT_HIGH, 'count' => 1));

    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($count);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(MODEL_PER_PAGE);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

    $this->view->paginator = $paginator;
    $this->view->items = $items;
```